# Returning single object and string from web api controller method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

I am in a situation where i need to return the single object along with string .. I am very new to web api and just could not be able to figure it out how to return multiple parameters ..

below is the code what i have tried so far ..

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuthenticationData(long id, string password)
    {
        Consumer consumer = await db.Consumers.FindAsync(id);

        if (consumer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(consumer.ConsumerPassword != password)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        ConsumerSessionTokenLog consumerSessionTokenLog = await db.ConsumerSessionTokenLogs.FindAsync(id);

        if(consumerSessionTokenLog == null)
        {
            return NotFound(); 
        }
        else
        {
            string sessionToken = consumerSessionTokenLog.SessionToken;
        }

  /// here i need to return "sessionToken" and "consumer" object 
        return Ok(consumer);
    }
```

Could any one please help on this query..

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class which wraps both values, or you can return an anonymous type like so:

```
return Ok(new { consumer, sessionToken });
```

Note that you'll need to hoist `sessionToken` out of your if-statement scope.

Comment: Thanks rob for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Joust define a struct to return:

```
struct MyReturType
{
   object obj;
   string str;

   public MyReturType(object o, string s)
   {
      obj = o;
      str = s;
   }
}
```

And then return that:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuthenticationData(long id, string password)
    {
        Consumer consumer = await db.Consumers.FindAsync(id);

        if (consumer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(consumer.ConsumerPassword != password)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        ConsumerSessionTokenLog consumerSessionTokenLog = await db.ConsumerSessionTokenLogs.FindAsync(id);

        if(consumerSessionTokenLog == null)
        {
            return NotFound(); 
        }
        else
        {
            string sessionToken = consumerSessionTokenLog.SessionToken;
        }

  /// here i need to return "sessionToken" and "consumer" object 
        return Ok(new MyReturType(consumer,sessionToken));
    }
```